# I'm trying out this problem of logic but I'm stuck "Simplify ¬(w∨(n∧¬w)) to ¬w∧¬n"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Here is my work so far, I would appreciate the help

```
 ¬(w∨(n∧¬w))
 ¬w∧¬(n∧¬w) (De Morgan's)
 ¬w∧(¬n∨¬¬w) (De Morgan's)
 ¬w∧(¬n∨w) (Double Negation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice start, continue with:

$\neg w \wedge (\neg n \vee w)$

$(\neg w \wedge \neg n) \vee (\neg w \wedge w)$ (distributivity of $\wedge$ over $\vee$)

$\neg w \wedge \neg n$ (because $\neg w \wedge w$ is always false)

Answer (score 0):

```
¬(p∨(q∧¬p))
¬p∧¬(q∧¬p)
¬p∧(¬q∨¬¬p)
¬p∧(¬q∨p)
(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧p)
(¬p∧¬q)∨(p∧¬p)
(¬p∧¬q)∨F
¬p∧¬q
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it would be better and more helpful to those who read your answer if you write how you simplified it: ie, you used De Morgan's laws, distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$, [LNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction) and double negation.